# php and mysql to create tabs with bootstrap 3

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/digj6.png)

How can I make a loop with php where I separate the comments as rounds

All comments for the round 1

```
<div id="$row['round']">
  $row['comments']
</div>
```

All comments for the round 2

```
<div id="$row['round']">
  $row['comments']
</div>
```

but I can have many rounds, so I don't know the exact query to use

Comment: Edit your question and paste the above comment in your question. It will be much cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="chat" class="chat">

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<?php
$stmt = $DB->query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE $id = video_id GROUP BY round ORDER BY round DESC");
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) { 
    echo '<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu'.$row['round'].'">'.$row['round'].'</a></li>';
}
?>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
<?php
$i=-1;
    $stmt = $DB->query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE $id = video_id GROUP BY round ORDER BY round DESC");
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) { 
        echo '<div class="tab-pane '.( $i = $i ? 'active' : '' ).'" id="menu'.$row['round'].'">';
        $test = $row['round'];
        $stmt2 = $DB->query("SELECT * FROM messages INNER JOIN system_users ON messages.user_id = u_userid WHERE $id = video_id AND $test = round ORDER BY date ASC");
        while ($row2 = $stmt2->fetch()) {  ?>
        <br />
            <p><b>round:</b> <?php echo $row2["round"]; ?></p>
            <p><b>Message:</b> <?php echo $row2["message"]; ?></p>
            <p><b>User:</b> <?php echo $row2["u_username"]; ?></p>
            <p><b>time:</b> <?php echo date_format (new DateTime($row2["date"]), 'd|m|Y H:i:s'); ?></p>
            <hr />
            <?php
    }$i =0;
    echo '</div>'; 
}
?>
</div>
```

I am completely sure this is not the best solution, but it is working, 
thanks anyway..